# Xcode 4.4 - iconset not found

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, icons

I'm developing an application for the Mac and I have created an iconset to provide high-res icon for my app. When I drag it to project and run, Xcode gives me an error telling that iconset is not found, but it is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange... Problem solved by moving my entire project folder from another folder to my Desktop. Now it's working fine.

Comment: Same for me, but I wouldn’t call it a solution.
I just can store all my projects on the desktop.
I think the path to the iconset isn’t escaped correctly.

Comment: The problem occurs even using the iconutil command from Terminal: just add, say, the accented character "é" in the name of any folder of the path and iconutil will throw the (rather imprecise) error "Iconset not found.". I’ll file the bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is a silly suggestion but it has solved many problems for me in the past, relating to importing artwork or other resources:

have you tried Cleaning and Building?
(COMMAND+SHIFT+K and COMMAND+B)

Comment: Yep, I have tried cleaning and building before import, after but no effect, same error